# create a List of different Type of Objects

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

```
class HeroClass
{
  skill1
  skill2
}

class Batman : HeroClass
{
  skill3
  skill4
}

class Robin : HeroClass
{
  skill3
  skill4
  skill5
}
```

I'm a beginner in programming. 
I want to make a List which can hold different Types of Objects.

If i create a list of Type `HeroClass` I am not able to access specific properties of object Type `Batman` or `Robin`

How can this be done?

Another question: as you can see class Batman and Robin have equal properties (3/4) would it be better to let "Robin" inherit from class "Batman"? These properties are totally same(polymorphism wouldn't make any sense) Is this a code smell if to classes have exact same properties?

Thank you a lot!!

Comment: you put the same properties into the HeroClass base class, and if you dont want to do that you can cast your batmanHero object to `((Batman)batmanHero).MySuperpower` to access props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first issue:**

> If i create a list of Type "HeroClass" i am not able to access specific properties of object Type "Batman" or "Robin"

You can access specific properties by casting object, for example:

```
var heroList = new List<HeroClass>();
 heroList.Add(new Batman { skill3 = "skill3" });
 heroList.Add(new Robin { skill5 = "skill5" });
 Console.WriteLine(((Batman)heroList[0]).skill3);
```

Live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhUadL)

**The second issue:**

> These properties are totally same(polymorphism wouldn't make any sense) Is this a code smell if to classes have exact same properties?

**Yes**, you should use `Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)` of [SOLID](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/damubetha/solid-principles-in-C-Sharp/)

> That clients should not be forced to implement interfaces they don't use. Instead of one fat interface many small interfaces are preferred based on groups of methods, each one serving one sub module

**For example**

```
    interface IHero
    {
        string skill1 { get; set; }
        string skill2 { get; set; }
    }

    interface IHero1234: IHero
    {
        string skill3 { get; set; }
        string skill4 { get; set; }
    }

    interface IHero12345: IHero1234
    {
        string skill5 { get; set; }
    }

    class BaseHero : IHero
    {
        public string skill1 { get; set; }
        public string skill2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Batman : IHero1234
    {
        public string skill1 { get; set; }
        public string skill2 { get; set; }
        public string skill3 { get; set; }
        public string skill4 { get; set; }
    }

    class Robin : IHero12345
    {
        public string skill1 { get; set; }
        public string skill2 { get; set; }
        public string skill3 { get; set; }
        public string skill4 { get; set; }
        public string skill5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Link live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GAueog)

Comment: Does this answer your question? @blender111

Comment: could you give me a code sample of your second advice? thx you

Comment: `skill1` `skill2` .. is property or method?

Comment: skill1, skill2 are properties

Comment: thx! after some research, it's a good solution in my case (casting an object is not an option)